# conditional expectation of discrete random variable given sum constraint

Tags: probability-theory

Given $k$ discrete iid random variables $X_1,\ldots,X_k$, the conditional expectation

$E[X_1\,|\,X_1+\cdots+X_k=n]$

is intuitively given by

$\frac{n}{k}$

since the variables are iid and, thus, given that their sum is $n$, each one is expected to contribute $\frac{n}{k}$. This leads to a nice (and well-known) recurrence formula for sums of random variables, namely,

$P[X_1+\cdots+X_k=n] = \frac{k}{n}\sum_{j} jP[X_1=j]P[X_2+\cdots+X_k=n-j].$

It would seem that one could extend this argumentation by claiming that, intuitively,

$E[X_1^2\,|\, X_1+\cdots+X_k=n]=(\frac{n}{k})^2$

but this appears to be wrong. Why so? What can be said about $E[X_1^2\,|\, X_1+\cdots+X_k=n]?$

Comment: The proof of the first is that $Z=E[X_i|X_1+\ldots+X_k=n]$ is the same for each $i$. Adding all $k$ of these $Z$'s, you get $E[X_1+\ldots+X_k|X_1+\ldots+X_k=n]=n$, so that $Z=n/k$. Similarly for the squares, you have $E[X_1^2|X_1+\ldots+X_k=n]=(1/k)E[X_1^2+\ldots+X_k^2|X_1+\ldots+X_k=n]$. The minimum value of the quantity in the expectation occurs when all the $X_i$ are equal to $n/k$, and so there is an inequality: $E[X_1^2|X_1+\ldots+X_k=n]\ge (n/k)^2$.

Comment: That's a good comment. I would think, then, that $E[X_1^2+\cdots+X_k^2\,|\, X_1+\cdots+X_k=n]=n^2-2E[\sum_{i<j} X_iX_j\,|\, X_1+\cdots+X_k=n]$. That appears to be the closest one get to a closed-form expression?

Comment: And then maybe $E[\sum_{i<j}X_iX_j\,|\,X_1+\cdots+X_k=n]=\binom{k}{2}E[X_1X_2\,|\, X_1+\cdots+X_k=n]$ since the variables are iid ...

Comment: So, to summarize, it appears that $E[X_1^2|X_1+\cdots+X_k=n]=\frac{1}{k}\Bigl(n^2-k(k+1)E[X_1X_2|X_1+\cdots+X_k=n]\Bigr)$. Anything one can do about the $E[X_1X_2|...]$ expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I answer this question myself, given the help provided by Anthony Quas. 
In order to prevent my question from being classified as "on hold", I'll also give a nice application of the derivations, showing that they imply the (non-obvious) relationship

(AA) $\binom{k}{n}=\frac{k}{n^2}\left(\binom{k-1}{n-1}+(k-1)\binom{k-2}{n-2}\right)$

holds for binomial coefficients.

As Anthony has outlined

$E[X_1^2|S_k=n]=\frac{1}{k}E[X_1^2+\cdots+X_k^2|S_k=n] = \frac{1}{k} E[S_k^2-2\sum_{i<j}X_iX_j|S_k=n] = \frac{1}{k}\left(n^2-k(k-1)E[X_1X_2|S_k=n]\right)$.

Now, by definition,

$E[X_1X_2|S_k=n] = \sum_{x,y}xyP[X_1=x,X_2=y|S_k=n] = \sum_{x,y}f(x)f(y)\frac{P[S_{k-2}=n-x-y]}{P[S_k=n]}$.

So, a closed-form formula is established for $E[X_1^2|S_k=n]$. Computing alternatively, we have $E[X_1^2|S_k=n] = \sum_{x}x^2\frac{f(x)P[S_{k-1}=n-x]}{P[S_k=n]}$, where $f(x)=P[X_1=x]$.

Now, equate both formulas for $E[X_1^2|S_k=n]$, rearrange, let $X_i$ be Bernoulli distributed with $p=1/2$ and obtain the curious relationship (AA)